# Throw Exception if two users want to persist same Object. What is the best approach?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an JSF application using Hibernate for persistence. Now how to resolve following problem:

User A opens a configuration page and edit some objects, but leave it open and will save later. User B opens the configuration for the same objects, edit them quickly and press save. So User A have a corrupt state now in his view.

I just want that User A gets a message that he have to refresh his view after he try to save.

How can I achieve to recognize this corrupted state? In my database (oracle) I have a version_id for the objects which works like a version counter for the object. One possibility is to hold the versionId by loading the edit view, and than compare before saving. But i need a much more generic approach, this would be too much work to do this for all my views.

Comment: I would not call it corrupted state, it is `changed` not corrupted. What about creating SHA256 hash for the information before and check, was it changed or not.

Comment: What you want to do is called [Optimistic Locking](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html#d0e2251).

Comment: You can use version annotation to resolve optimistic locking scenario

Comment: I already have the version annotation, but still, if I call the "persist" function with the `changed` state, no exception is thrown by hibernate. What am I missing, I am also wondering how hibernate can know about different users.

Answer (score 0):

User A and User B are updating a portion of the object graph that do not overlap. So Hibernate's optimistic concurrency control will not help detect this, because from Hibernate's view there is no data conflict and no lost updates.

Since your business logic dictates that the whole object graph is now stale. One way to solve this is by marking the root node of your object graph as having been modified manually whenever a portion of the object graph changes, and by this way Hibernate can throw Stale object state exception.

One way of doing a manual version update is below:
[Updating hibernate version manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299430/updating-hibernate-version-manually)